# django __str__ return all the attributes

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way in django `__str__` to output all attributes in one shot instead of doing one by one like I'm doing here? I'm planning to have about 100 attributes so putting all in the str method doesn't seem right.

```
class Carmodel(models.Model):
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=2016)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    styles = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

     def __str__(self):
         return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.year, self.make, self.model, self.styles)
```

Comment: Woow.. that is one hell of a `__str__` method.. Are you sure you want do that ?

Comment: @karthikr my django skills are weak so not sure if my approach is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's a good idea, but for the sake of answering your question, loop on model fields and use `getattr` to get the value:

```
def __str__(self):
    field_values = []
    for field in self._meta.get_all_field_names():
        field_values.append(getattr(self, field, ''))
    return ' '.join(field_values)
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Django 1.10+ `get_all_field_names` is removed and now we have to use `get_fields`

Updated version looks like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    field_values = []
    for field in self._meta.get_fields():
        field_values.append(str(getattr(self, field.name, '')))
    return ' '.join(field_values)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [meta api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model) to get a list of all the field names. Then you can loop through the fields and use `getattr` to get the value for each field.